# memset and a dynamic array of std::complex<double>

Tags: c++, memset

since std::complex is a non-trivial type, compiling the following with GCC 8.1.1

```
complex<double>* z = new complex<double>[6];
memset(z,0,6*sizeof*z);
delete [] (z);`
```

produces a warning

> clearing an object of non-trivial type

My question is, is there actually any potential harm in doing so?

Comment: Why do you think you need the `memset()` at all for this? The array should be initialized correctly already. Also better simply use a `std::vector<complex<double>> z(6);` to achieve what you want.

Comment: I don't use it like this. It is just a way how to provoke the warning.

Comment: Note that in this case, the `memset` is entirely redundant. `new complex<double>[6]` invokes the default constructor of `std::complex<double>` on each element of the array, which is equivalent to zeroing out both the real and imaginary parts. In other words, the `memset` duplicates the work done as part of the `new[]` call.

Comment: Yeah, see my comment above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior of [`std::memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) is only defined if the pointer it is modifying is a pointer to a [TriviallyCopyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) type. [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) is guaranteed to be a *LiteralType*, but, as far as I can tell, it isn't guaranteed to be *TriviallyCopyable*, meaning that `std::memset(z, 0, ...)` is not portable.

That said, `std::complex` has an [array-compatibility guarantee](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex#Array-oriented_access), which states that the storage of a `std::complex<T>` is exactly two consecutive `T`s and can be reinterpreted as such. This seems to suggest that `std::memset` is actually fine, since it would be accessing through this array-oriented access. It may also imply that `std::complex<double>` *is* *TriviallyCopyable*, but I am unable to determine that.

If you wish to do this, I would suggest being on the safe side and `static_assert`ing that `std::complex<double>` is *TriviallyCopyable*:

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<std::complex<double>>::value);
```

If that assertion holds, then you are guaranteed that the `memset` is safe.

---

In either case, it would be safe to use `std::fill`:

```
std::fill(z, z + 6, std::complex<double>{});
```

It [optimizes down](https://godbolt.org/g/W63P8r) to a call to `memset`, albeit with a few more instructions before it. I would recommend using `std::fill` unless your benchmarking and profiling showed that those few extra instructions are causing problems.

Comment: It does optimize for GCC and clang, but apparently not when I select X64 MSVC on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Never, never, ever `memset` non-POD types. They have constructors *for a reason*. Just writing a bunch of bytes on top of them is highly unlikely to give the desired result (and if it does, the types themselves are badly designed as they should clearly then just be POD in the first place - or you are simply being unlucky that Undefined Behaviour *seems to work* in *this* case - have fun debugging it when it doesn't after you change optimization level, compiler or platform (or moon phase)).

Just don't do this.

Comment: The thing that makes this interesting is that `std::complex<T>` can legally be interpreted as an array of `T` with `c[0] == c.real()` and `c[1] == c.imag()`. Further, an array of `std::complex<T>` can be interpreted as an array of `T` of alternating real and imaginary parts. So this specific case requires some special consideration

Comment: going along with @Justin comment because of those requirements most likely `sizeof(std::complex<double>)` is equal to `sizeof(double) * 2` and if it is there is no reason `memset` would be an issue.

Comment: @Justin Even if you *can* do it in this case, why risk it? It's simply too fragile and error prone to try and do stuff like this. And it probably won't even be measurably faster in any way that actually *matters*.

Comment: @NathanOliver Not just most likely; `sizeof(std::complex<double>) == sizeof(double) * 2` is guaranteed

Comment: @Jesper Juhl Fair enough. I was just not sure if there isn't an exception for the std::complex<T> class due to the C compatibility requirement. It actually is trivially copyable and the requirements defined in the Implementation notes section at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex do not leave many options how to break it. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Jesper Juhl ... again talking about the GCC compiler.

Comment: @Zdenek Prusa One whould *not* write compiler specific code. One should write *standard compliant* code that is guaranteed to work the same across different compilers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that for a standard-compliant `std::complex` there is no need for `memset` after `new`.

`new complex<double>[6]` will initialize the complex to `(0, 0)` because it calls a default (non-trivial) constructor that initializes to zero. 
(I think this is a mistake unfortunately.) 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/complex

If the code posted was just and example with missing code between `new` and `memset`, then `std::fill` will do the right thing. 
(In part because the specific standard library implementation knows internally how `std::complex` is implemented.)